# Are the PS Plus exclusive skin's available on my account if I am not the consoles PS Plus subscriber?

Tags: playstation-plus, fortnite-battle-royale

I have  been trying to get the PS Plus exclusive skin for Fortnite on my account but I don't have PS Plus. Although one of the accounts on the PS4 has PS Plus, so can I still get the skin on my account if I go to the PlayStation store or can I download it on the account that has PS Plus and it will show up on my account?

Answer (score 1):

Only the user account that has PS+ will get the benefit.  If my girlfriend and I both want to play online or get skins on my PS4 we both have to buy PS+ for our accounts.  Sorry!

You will only be able to use the skin on the account with PS+

Comment: Not entirely true. If one member on the PS4 has a PS+ account, other users can share and play game downloads and play online so long as that PS4 is activated as the Primary PS4. Though this game sharing feature does not allow sub accounts to download anything from PS+, but only play games that have already been downloaded by the PS+ member. This only applies to games. Items like skins, etc. cannot be share across accounts. Source: https://www.androidcentral.com/how-use-family-sharing-playstation-plus